# Convergence in distribution ( Two equivalent definitions)

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus

I read that for convergence in distribution it is equivalent to have that either the characteristic functions of the random variables convergence pointwise or we have that $F_{X_n} \rightarrow F_{X}$ pointwise, where $F$(the distribution function) is continuous.

I could not find a proof of this, so I was wondering how hard it is to show? Does anybody here have a (Internet)-reference or could sketch the idea?

Comment: I am not so sure whether you are asking is that or not but probably you can find it in Davar Khoshnevisan's Probability book. Chapter 7. Page 92.

Comment: Yeah, actually the question that comes to mind reading this is WHICH are the textbooks you are using? (And pointwise convergence of the characteristic functions does not imply convergence in distribution.)

Comment: to answer your question, I do not have any book on this currently around here, so I would have to go to the library anyway....ah, so only the converse(convergence in distribution implies pointwise convergence of the characteristic functions) is true?

Comment: More precisely, $F_{X_n} \rightarrow F_{X}$ in the points of continuity, Lévy's continuity theorem : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%99s_continuity_theorem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Durrett's probability book](http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf) appears to still be free (on author's page). Your subject is embedded in Chapter 3 Central Limit Theorems (Weak Convergence, Characteristic Functions etc., leading to Continuity Theorem 3.3.6).

Rick Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples book **Theorem 3.3.6. Levy's continuity theorem:**

Let $\mu_n$, $1\leq n \leq \infty$ be probability measures with characteristic functions $\phi_n$.

**(i)** If $\mu_n$ converges weakly to $\mu_\infty$, then $\phi_n(t)$ converges pointwise to $\phi_\infty(t)$.

**(ii)** If $\phi_n(t)$ converges pointwise to a limit $\phi(t)$ that is continuous at $0$, then the associated sequence of distributions $\mu_n$ is tight and converges weakly to a measure $\mu$ with characteristic function $\phi$.

Statement (i) follows from the [Portmanteau Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) characterization of weakly convergence that uses bounded and continuous functions, by noting that $\mathrm e^{itx}$ is bounded and continuous in $x$.

For (ii), Durrett first proves that sequence of distributions $\mu_n$ is tight (not easy, uses the continuity of $\phi$ at $0$; I'll try to update some details later), which in turn implies the existence of a weakly convergent subsequence. The distribution, call it $\mu$, this subsequence converges weakly to, must have characteristic function $\phi$. Moreover, every subsequence has a further subsequence that converges weakly to $\mu$. Using again the Portmanteau Theorem characterization mentioned above (and a general topological fact: if every subsequence has a further subsequence that converges to some point, then the whole sequence converges to that point) one can show that the whole sequence of distributions $\mu_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$.

**Edit:** The tightness follows from the observation that:
$$ \mu_n\left(\{x\;|\;|x|>2u^{-1} \}\right) \leq u^{-1}\int_{-u}^u (1- \phi_n(t))dt,$$
using Fubini's theorem to re-write the integral as:
$$ u^{-1}\int_{-u}^u (1- \phi_n(t))dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(1- \frac{\sin(ux)}{ux}\right)\mu_n(dx),$$
and the fact that $|\sin x|\leq |x|$ for all $x$.

**Edit2**: For relationship of tightness and weak convergence topology see also [Prokhorov's Theorem and its corollaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prokhorov%27s_theorem).

Comment: Please try to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link to the text for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @ArthurFischer I edited Durrett's theorem text and some proof ideas. I'll try to clarify later.

Comment: @ir7 Could you please elaborate how you got the inequality of your observation?